# Распространённое определение или длинное подлежащее?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот, определения

Предложение:

> Укладка как из салона красоты каждый день — это реально?

Я помню, что это не совсем сравнительный оборот и запятая вроде как не нужна: если бы было "укладка красивая, как из салона красоты", тогда да, а здесь нет. Но конструкция слишком длинная, плюс мне не очень понятно, чем оно является. Теоретически вроде определение (укладка какая?), но это может быть и целой подлежащной конструкцией. Что это и обособляется ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто для информации:
Розенталь:
Сравнительный оборот с союзом *как* не выделяется запятыми, если он входит в сказуемое (образует именную часть составного сказуемого) или по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым (обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без сравнительного оборота):
*Как солнышко она.

Всё как у людей.

Скота у них как муравьев в муравейнике.

Волосы у девочки как солома.

Вся жизнь его как светлый праздник.

Душонка у тебя как у зайца.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147

Но в данном примере сказуемое уже есть — *это реально*. Из-за этого фраза не звучит цельно. Поэтому сравнительный оборот нужно обособить с двух сторон. Без вопросительной интонации это становится очевидным:
*Укладка, как из салона красоты, каждый день — это реально.*

Сравнительные обороты не входят в подлежащее, но могут являться сказуемым или входить в него.

Примечание: для сравнительных оборотов не обязательно наличие прилагательного при существительном.